# removing pattern from lines in a file using sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to remove a pattern from all lines in a file. The pattern is `'id': null` and the two `sed` attempts I have made execute but the file is unchanged.. Thank you :).

**file**

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "version": "1a",
        "chromosome": "chr1",
                "id": null,
                "peptide": "123",
    },
    {
        "version": "1a",
        "chromosome": "chr1",
                "id": "This line has text and is printed.",
                "peptide": null,
    },
    {
        "version": '1a',
        "chromosome": "chr17",
                "id": null,
                "peptide": null}, 
                "id": 'This has text in it and this line is printed as well',
                "end": 460
            }
]
}
```

**desired**

```
{
"objects": [
    {
        "version": "1a",
        "chromosome": "chr1",
        "peptide": "123",
    },
    {
        "version": "1a",
        "chromosome": "chr1",
                "id": "This line has text and is printed.",
                "peptide": null,
    },
    {
        "version": '1a',
        "chrmosome": "chr17",
                "id": null,
                "peptide": null}, 
                "id": 'This has text in it and this line is printed as well',
                "end": 460
            }
]
}
```

**sed**

```
sed '/"id": *null/s/, [^,]*/ /' file --- if "id": null found substitute with blank up to the ending ,
sed -E "s/"id": *null, *//" file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `gnu-sed`:

```bash
sed 0,'/"id": null,/{//d}' file
```

This will remove first instance of `"id": null,` from file

---

**Original answer based on original question:**

```bash
sed -E "s/'id': *None, *//" file

{'version': '1a', 'chr': '17', 'xref_json': None}, 'id': 'This has text in it and this line is printed', 'end': 460}
{'version': '1a', 'chr': '17', 'xref_json': None}
```

`s/'id': *None, *//` searches for pattern `'id':<0 or more spaces>None,<0 or more spaces>` and replaces that with empty string.

Comment: I also found a different  data type I can not seem to fix, I updated the post with the details. Thank you :).

Comment: Unfortunately, now this question has become a totally different question.

Comment: You can try: `sed 0,'/"id": null,/{//d}' file` (will require gnu sed)

Comment: Thank you, I will keep trying and appreciate the help :).